# In Javascript, how can I reference a function-scoped variable from a function called within that function but defined elsewhere?

Tags: javascript, scope

I have a Javascript function something like this, defined in a place I can't change it:

```
foo.customSave = [];

foo.save = function() {
    var saveString = 'initial value';
    // stuff about saveString here
    for (i in foo.customSave) { foo.customSave[i](); }
    // more stuff about saveString here, including actually saving it
};
```

Then I have my own code like this:

```
bar.init = function() {
    // other init stuff here
    foo.customSave.push(function() {
        saveString += 'something meaningful here';
    });
    // more other init stuff here
};
```

`bar.init()` is called at an appropriate time (which is to say, before `foo.save()` is called).  The problem seems to be that `saveString` is not defined when I try to add `'something meaningful here'` to it (putting a `console.log` call there confirms this).

**Is there any way my `customSave` function can access that string, or am I stuck?**

Comment: `saveString` is only accessible in function `foo.save`, you cannot access it from elsewhere

Comment: without being able to change `foo` you have zero chance of accessing saveString outside of `foo.save`

Comment: The only way I can think is either make it in global scope (which you likely won't want to do) or pass it as a function parameter.

Comment: Use function parameters and return values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that you can't modify the function associated with `foo.save`, there is no way you can modify the `saveString` variable. The reason for this is because `saveString` is a local variable that is scoped to function associated with `foo.save`. As a result, you can call the function, but it basically acts as a black box where you can't access the variables defined it in (in fact, without looking at the source code, you wouldn't even know that the `saveString` variable existed).

Within the function associated with `bar.init`, you're creating a new function object each time `bar.init` is called and pushing it to an array. And because you haven't used `var` to declare the `saveString` variable, JavaScript will try to find the `saveString` variable within the function being pushed to an array. Since it can't find the declaration there, JavaScript will continue looking up the variable in the next outer scope which the the function associated with `bar.init`. Since it can't find it there either, JavaScript will lastly try to find it in the global scope (and won't have success there either).

Hope that helps, but long story short, without being able to modify `foo.save`, you're stuck.

Comment: I was afraid of that.  Back to the drawing board…

Answer (score 0):

How about adding `saveString` as a property of `foo`?

Like so:

```
foo.customSave = [];

foo.saveString = '';

foo.save = function() {
    foo.saveString = 'initial value';
    // stuff about saveString here
    for (i in foo.customSave) { foo.customSave[i](); }
    // more stuff about saveString here, including actually saving it
};
```

Then:

```
bar.init = function() {
    // other init stuff here
    foo.customSave.push(function() {
        foo.saveString += 'something meaningful here';
    });
    // more other init stuff here
};
```

Comment: Can't change foo.save().